# jQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had code that looked like this:

```
jQuery('.views-row').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).find('.views-field-field-doctor-indicator').length != 0) {
        jQuery(this).css("padding","0px");
        jQuery('.views-field-title span a', this).css("color","#00476b");
        jQuery('.views-field', this).wrapAll('<div class="physician-indicator"></div>');
    } 
});
```

But realized that since there is a bit of ajax going on in the page that it would not continue to work after a user hit enter for a search. You can basically see what it does, but to explain it a little more humanized, it basically is used to sort through doctors and add certain attributes to the ones that are needed.

I tried using this:

```
jQuery('#block-views-homepage-redo-block').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
    var target = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.views-row', target).each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).find('.views-field-field-doctor-indicator').length != 0) {
            jQuery(this).css("padding","0px");
            jQuery('.views-field-title span a', this).css("color","#00476b");
            jQuery('.views-field', this).wrapAll('<div class="physician-indicator"></div>');
        } 
    });
});
```

which seems to me as very similar, just that it would do the same stuff whenever the content changes. But, i get this error:

```
jQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I understand what the error means for the most part, but i dont understand what would make such the big difference in breaking the page.

**--- EDIT ---**

This is what worked for me. I added another check in to see if the div was already created. This allows the code to step over anything that has the div created that I needed to make in the first place.

```
jQuery('#block-views-homepage-doctors-redo-block').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
    var target = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.views-row', target).each(function(){
        var switchTarget = jQuery(this);
        if(!switchTarget.children().hasClass('physician-indicator')) {
            if(jQuery(switchTarget).find('.views-field-field-doctor-indicator').length != 0) {
                jQuery(switchTarget).css("padding","0px");
                jQuery('.views-field-title span a', switchTarget).css("color","#00476b");
                jQuery('.views-field', switchTarget).wrapAll('<div class="physician-indicator"></div>');
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're inserting an element everytime you're inserting an element, so it's basically an endless loop that inserts elements, and that fills up the callstack.

It's the `wrapAll` that triggers the `DOMNodeInserted`, and that triggers another `wrapAll`, that triggers another `DOMNodeInserted`, and so it goes ...

Comment: ahh, So what would be a better way of trying to do what i need where i can avoid such a thing from happening?

Comment: Why do you use the domNodeInserted event to being with, and why do you insert new elements whenever an element is inserted? You should avoid doing those things, and the problem will be solved

Comment: haha, yeah i guess that is true. unfortunately my issue here is that i still need to have that `wrapAll` in there, but i also need it to recognize that the amount of fields are changing due to the search for the doctors and it needs to add the wrap to it all again

Comment: Well, there's not much I can do, other than to tell you why you're getting the error, and that the only way to get rid of it is to not recursively insert elements like that ?

Comment: Well even though i didn't get a solution, you did answer my question. thank you

Comment: I was, however, able to find out a solution to my issue which was adding another check (for anyone interested in the future). Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late and the answer above led me to the answer I needed, but in case someone needs it spelled out a little more.

In the updated example above instead of including a check within your each block, you could probably use 'one' instead of 'bind'

```
jQuery('#block-views-homepage-doctors-redo-block').one('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
var target = jQuery(this);
jQuery('.views-row', target).each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).find('.views-field-field-doctor-indicator').length != 0) {
        jQuery(this).css("padding","0px");
        jQuery('.views-field-title span a', this).css("color","#00476b");
        jQuery('.views-field', this).wrapAll('<div class="physician-indicator"></div>');
    } 
});
```

});

This way it'd only fire once and you wouldn't end up with the stack overflow error. Now maybe you want it to fire every single time a user searches. What I'd suggest is adding the single(using 'one') event handler when a search is triggered.